# Using Word Embeddings in Clustering and Topic Modelling

Tags: clustering, natural-language, text-mining, word-embeddings, topic-models

I am new to the field of NLP and would appreciate any guidance please. I am trying to understand how word embeddings can be used in clustering and topic modelling. If I create word embeddings for every word in a corpus, with e.g. 4 dimensions per embedding, the number of features becomes 4X more than a bag of words model and also I am unsure as to how you could feed a series of word embeddings into a model as the structure of the dataset would be different to a 'one feature per column' format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you use word embeddings, you can use any standard clustering algorithm since they are based on distance metrics which are defined even for higher dimensions. An example process could be:

1. Convert words to embeddings.
2. Run K-means clustering to obtain groups of words.
3. View examples in each cluster to label possible topics you notice.

Step 3 can be annoying since it is manual, but this can be further automated like so!

1. Collect centroids (cluster centers) from step 2 above.
2. Create a list of possible topics and convert them into embeddings.
3. Compare similarities between the centroids and topic embeddings to label the clusters (i.e. run a 1-nearest neighbor classifier)

Comment: How do you “create a list of possible topics”? Is this passage also automated? Or does it require manual coding?

Comment: You would do this yourself, if you know what type of topics you’d like to setup. For example, if it’s about movies or literature, you would create a list of possible genres. Do you know what types of topics you’re aiming for?

Comment: Thanks variational. In my example, What im not grasping is I'm thinking of a document term matrix. if you add an extra series of dimensions for every word based on word embeddings, you are left with a series of columns where you cannot accurately compare dimension one of word 1 with dimension 1 of word 2 because dimension 1-4 of words 1 and 2 are all treated the same as all they are is one of a very large series of columns?